# how to save the images in the fly in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, backend

I'm using **Django** view, and I'm trying to **save the image on the fly** and **pass it** to the **template HTML**

This is the **view.py**

```
def img_upscaler(request):
 # some code 
 upscaled = sr.upsample(image)
 cv2.imwrite("result.png", upscaled)
 return  render(request, "upsc_main.html",{'form': form})
```

I want the result of the **cv2.imwrite** method to be **saved on the fly** and **passed** in render to be called in the HTML **template**. I tried many ways to do it and I can't get it. any help?

***thank you in advance.***

Comment: Main problem will be how the browser can *fetch* the image.

Comment: use PIL instead. opencv is for computer vision. this isn't computer vision.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a dynamic image URL and render it in your template. Here's how you can do that:

Update your img_upscaler view to generate a dynamic image URL:

```py
import cv2
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

def img_upscaler(request):
    # Some code to upscale the image (sr.upsample(image))
    upscaled = sr.upsample(image)
    
    # Save the image to a temporary location
    temp_image_path = "temp/result.png"
    cv2.imwrite(temp_image_path, upscaled)
    
    # Create a dynamic image URL
    image_url = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, temp_image_path)

    # Pass the image URL to the template
    return render(request, "upsc_main.html", {'image_url': image_url})
```

In your HTML template (upsc_main.html), you can use the image_url to display the image using an img tag:

```html
<img src="{{ image_url }}" alt="Upscaled Image">
```

In your Django project settings (usually settings.py), you need to configure media file handling. Add the following settings:

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Add URL patterns for serving media files in your project's urls.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# Add this at the end of your project's urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```